# Why is Dirac Lagrangian in Curved Spacetime Weyl Invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Are there any references on the Weyl invariance of the Dirac Lagragian in general spacetime?

Comment: I presume you mean massless Dirac Lagrangian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (massless) Dirac Lagrangian is Weyl invariant on-shell. Please see the following [review article](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0307199) by Forger and Romer. In this article, a theorem (5.1) was formulated stating that actions have stress energy tensors of vanishing trace iff they are locally Weyl invariant on shell.

Comment: How could the Dirac Lagrangian be Weyl invariant with a mass term? I assume you mean massless, but then, please say so.